# Retrieving Column Value for Updating Anoher Table Column in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a sync system. And I have a table for **sync product quantities**

I want to update my product table.

Here is my code

```
DB::table('products')->update(['stock_quantity' => function($query){
    $query->select('BAKIYE')->from('sync_stocks')->whereRaw(DB::raw('`products`.`stock_no` = `sync_stocks`.`IND`'));
}]);
```

Here is DB::statement version of my code.

```
DB::statement("UPDATE `products` as p SET `stock_quantity` = (SELECT `BAKIYE` FROM `sync_stocks` as s WHERE p.`stock_no` = s.`IND`)");
```

**Error:** Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Where am I making mistake ?

**UPDATE:**

I have two tables. products and sync_stocks

sync_stocks has only two column (IND, BAKIYE)

I'm getting stock quantities in another server. (Note: mssql server)

I'm working on mysql. I want to get all data from BAKIYE to stock_quantity in products table.

Comment: Whats the problem with this?

Comment: And are you getting an error?..

Comment: no i'm not getting error. It is inside try catch block. But nothing shown

Comment: And is sync_stocks.ind is the FK of products? why are you comparing a stock_no with an indication column

Comment: Error : Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Comment: Suddenly are you getting an error? which row is causing this error?

Comment: sagi i updated my topic.